# How to hide a element in legend of a pie (Highchart)?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to hide a element of legend under certain condition. The condition is given below. But it's not working. Is it achievable? How can I hide a specific element in legend? This snippet is from directive I'm using.

```
legend: {
    itemWidth: 200,
    itemMarginTop: 1,
    itemStyle: {
      color: '#000000',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      fontSize: '90%'
    },
    formatter:function() {
        if(this.y != 0 && !scope.item.quotaEnable) {
            return this.point.name;
        }

        if(this.y == 0 && scope.item.quotaEnable && this.point.name == 'Free Space') {
            return this.point.name;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can manipulate on particular SVG element, could you recreate your example as live demo and let me know which shold be disable?

Comment: [Related ticket](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4545) on the github.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatCop/20nvj28c/) Please have a look. I'm afraid this may not run but you'll get an overview about what I want to achieve for sure. Thanks in advance.